# Problems styling select elements in a fluid layout

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problem:

I have a medium to highly complex search page for a portal. It contains at least 8 select elements in container using a percentage-based fluid grid. At least one select should support multiple selections.

#### In summary I have these prerequisites:

- style `<select>` elements
- style `<select multiple>` elements
- no pixel-width (should support percentage-based width)
- ideally jQuery based

I did try a number of existing plugins which I will name now including the reasons why they did not work for me.

#### Tried but did not work, why:

- [jQuery.customSelect()](http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/)

  - does not resize well: needs to have `render` event triggered on window resize (horrible performance)
  - does not support multi-selects
- [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

  - not possible to deactive search box on top

    - unsuitable for some of the normal select inputs
  - *might be an option for multiple selects*
- [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

  - too focused on twitter bootstrap: does not play nice with the custom grid

### What I need:

I either need a solution that works well for all cases, or a solution that works well for non-multi-selects to use together with chosen/select2.

*EDIT:* I need to use a given design, therefore I need a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to use [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and modify it as needed. It is far from an ideal option, but I spend too much time on this minor problem already.

Answer (score 0):

Without Code its rather guessing then knowing, but you can try this:

```
select {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -web-kit-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px; /* Or what ever you need, and with box-sizing its fitting nicely */
}
```

And you wouldn't even need jquery/addons . . .

Comment: No I'm afraid I need the plugins to make the elements look like the given design document I have to follow, then I have to make the styled elements play nice with the fluid layout. I did not include code as the problems arise from the specific plugins I mentioned.